# How can I access variable from object?

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out how to access pubOuter, can anyone figure this one out? It keeps returning *undefined*, because I can't find a way how pass **outer** from **inner2()** function. Or I'm missing something obvious. Many thanks.

**Javascript**

```
var myObject = (function(){
   var outer;

   function inner1(IN_number){
     outer = IN_number*2;
   }

   function inner2(){
     inner1(10);
     return outer;
   }


   return {
     pubFnInner1: inner1,
     pubFnInner2: inner2,
     pubOuter:    outer
   };

})();

$("#click").on("click", function(){
   console.log("outer" + myObject.pubOuter);  
});
```

**HTML**

```
<button id="click">Click</button>
```

Comment: We need more information. From what I see without a function call to `inner1`, then `outer` will be undefined. To be clear, you need to call it before the `return {...}`, afterwards `outer` will be out of scope and no longer able to be edited.

Comment: otherwise call inner2(); before the return statement.

Comment: That's what happens when u work excessive hours!!! I missed the call to function:) Thanks Spencer!

Comment: the original code is too complex, I've just made some rough approximation. Thanks guys!

Comment: I'm not a moderator but, if you could, please post your answer mark it as _the answer_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are successfully accessing the `putOuter` property. The problem is that it hasn't been set to anything before you're using it.

I've modified the code to initialize `outer` to `1`. Otherwise, when you multiply it by `IN_number` in the `inner1` function, it will result in `NaN`.

```
var myObject = (function(){
   var outer = 1;

   function inner1(IN_number){
     outer = IN_number*2;
   }

   function inner2(){
     inner1(10);
     return outer;
   }


   return {
     pubFnInner1: inner1,
     pubFnInner2: inner2,
     pubOuter:    outer
   };

})();

$("#click").on("click", function(){

   console.log("outer" + myObject.pubOuter);
   myObject.pubFnInner1(10);
   console.log("outer" + myObject.pubOuter);

   // or combine both steps by using your pubFnInner2 method.
   console.log("outer" + myObject.pubFnInner2());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`pubOuter` is undefined because you're assigning it to `outer` which is undefined because you never run `inner1`, you need to do this:

```
var myObject = (function(){
   var outer;

   function inner1(IN_number){
     outer = IN_number*2;
   }

   function inner2(){
     inner1(10);
     return outer;
   }


   return {
     pubFnInner1: inner1(),
     pubFnInner2: inner2(),
     pubOuter:    outer
   };

})();

$("#click").on("click", function(){
   console.log("outer" + myObject.pubOuter);  
});
```